# How do I make this work? Fetching 3 apis with axios and render the data in FlatList

Tags: react-native, axios, react-native-flatlist

Trust me, I searched different ways to do this, google it the h..ll out of it, Please help.

```
const App = () => {


const Fetch = () => {
    let one = "EXAMPLEAPI"
    let two = "EXAMPLEAPI"
    let three = "EXAMPLEAPI"

    const requestOne = axios.get(one);
    const requestTwo = axios.get(two);
    const requestThree = axios.get(three);

    axios.all([requestOne, requestTwo, requestThree]).then(axios.spread((...responses) => {
        const responseOne = responses[0]
        const responseTwo = responses[1]
        const responseThree = responses[2]
        return (
            <FlatList
                keyExtractor={item => item.title}
                data={responses}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    return <Text>{item.title}</Text>
                }}
            />
        )
    })).catch(errors => {
        console.error(errors);
    });
}

return (
    <SafeAreaView>
        <Text>PRESS</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={Fetch}
        >
        <Text>HERE</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </SafeAreaView>
)
}


export default App;
```

If I console.log(responses) I get everything from the object, not only the data I need. How to I use only the data that I need from responses?
Not working by passing the "responses" in the "data"(not getting anything).

Can anyone make a FlatList using data from 3 apis? I surely CAN NOT :(((

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should separate UI/JSX and your request. Return JSX due to an successful request isn‘t a good approach.

Rather add the Flatlist to your Dom and fill flatlists data property.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  SafeAreaView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native';

import * as axios from 'axios';

const App = () => {
  const [responses, setResponses] = React.useState([]);

  const Fetch = () => {
    const one = 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/';
    const two = 'https://swapi.dev/api/films/';
    const three = 'https://swapi.dev/api/planets/';

    const requestOne = axios.get(one);
    const requestTwo = axios.get(two);
    const requestThree = axios.get(three);

    axios
      .all([requestOne, requestTwo, requestThree])
      .then(
        axios.spread((...resp) => {
          const responseOne = resp[0].data.results;
          const responseTwo = resp[1].data.results;
          const responseThree = resp[2].data.results;

          setResponses([...responseOne, ...responseTwo, ...responseThree]);
        })
      )
      .catch((errors) => {
        console.error(errors);
      });
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View
        style={{
          height: 150,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          backgroundColor: '#cccccc',
        }}>
        <Text>PRESS</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={Fetch}>
          <Text>HERE</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View>
        <FlatList
          keyExtractor={({item})=> {item}}
          data={responses}
          renderItem={({item}) => {
            return <Text>{item.title || item.name}</Text>;
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I have created an expo [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/separate-axios-and-ui)

To use api https://api.netbet.com/development:

Change

```
       const responseOne = resp[0].data.results;
       const responseTwo = resp[1].data.results;
       const responseThree = resp[2].data.results;
```

To

```
      const responseOne = resp[0].data.data.items;
      const responseTwo = resp[1].data.data.items;
      const responseThree = resp[2].data.data.items;
```

Comment: Can you upvote my answer.

Comment: I did but it won't let me. It's asking at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but it also said that my feedback has been recorded. Thank You So Much !!!

Comment: I added my api and I get the error " Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'iter[Symbol.iterator]')

Comment: I guess you try to iterate over an object which is not iterateable.
The data structure of your endpoints api is different from swapi.dev.

Comment: Dear Mr. "The only one that can help me with API's" :) Can you please help me with this one also? "https://diacut.ro/PPL/get_question.php?id=1" I need to get all elements, but first I have to get out the 'answers', Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I have to display them something like this: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/efPTiNkstlk/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: Create a new Question and post the link